# wise way to use angular-ui tab to have multiple dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

What I want is each of tab consist of its dynamic content, but now I doubt I was doing it correctly when I put ng-view within ng-repeat.

Here is a working version to push http://plnkr.co/edit/19sAXoEW4HZ9G7CT7R3a?p=preview . So in the beginning it was fine for me.

But after that I felt I've to load some data, the tab no longer working working when I do $scope.tasks = tasks
which tasks is a object in data.js. Here is the error : http://plnkr.co/edit/jbxypSlvk3rYlFAIHygo?p=preview

Comment: You need to give some more context(and maybe some pseudo code).  Is the goal just to swap out the main container with the tab that is clicked?  Or are you trying to sync the url/view.  Two issues I see right away is you can only have one ng-view per page and u are missing quotes around `active="tab.active"`

Comment: @Nix No. what I want is pretty basic, todo lists that has groups, that is it. The first link although it worked but I doubt it's a appropriate way. The 2nd link shows I want to load the data in but the tab isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes on `active=tab.active` change to `active="tab.active"`.

Which causes the

> Error: The string contains invalid characters.

Why are you shoe-horning tabs here.  I think a  simple nav would do.  The underlying issue is your design is fundamentally flawed, you can only have one `ng-view` on a page.  If you update your post I can recommend a solution.